# using nohup even after a complete shutdown or sudo reboot, Possible?

Tags: linux, shutdown, sudo, reboot, nohup

I am using `nohup python -u nationalbiblioteket_logs.py --query 0 > log_q0.out &` in my Ubuntu 16.04 machine as an administrator to run really time and memory consuming program.

I am already aware that `nohup` will still continue after closing down the terminal according to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1449188/is-it-possible-for-nohup-command-still-running-even-when-the-user-logged-out) post!

My question is, however, whether or not I could use `nohup` for running my scripts even after a complete system shutdown or `sudo reboot`?

If not, is there any alternative I could probably use instead for leaving the program running?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

If you shutdown your system nothing is running there. So idea about `nohup` make no sense.

About reboot: you start a program and reboot the machine. And the process disappear because it was killed during reboot process. And nothing start it back.

Comment: Is there any alternative for `nohup` to run script even after shutdown or reboot?

Comment: Yes, there are alternatives. But this is another question: https://superuser.com/questions/ask